# Clarification When Making .net Framework 4.8 WinForm C# HDPI Aware

Tags: c#, winforms

I have spent some time researching how to make my win form .Net 4.8 Framework app HDPI aware and would just like some clarification from those who have more experience than I do.

I have watched a Microsoft Video from 2 presenters who work on the.NetFramework team and they explain that the app.manifest has to include Windows 10

```
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>

      <!-- Windows 10 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />

    </application>
  </compatibility>
```

They then explain that the app.config file has to include DpiAwareness PerMonitorV2 for it to work across multiple monitors which have different scaling applied.

```
<System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
        <add key="DpiAwareness" value="PerMonitorV2"/>  
 
</System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
```

I have since read on the Microsoft website that using the Manifest approach is not recommended now because it can override the app.config file so I am a little confused.

Can anyone who uses the HDPI Awareness clarify what they use when targeting .Net Framework 4.7 or higher please.

Comment: It's what you have heard from the MS developers: in .NET Framework 4.7.2+, you specify the DPI Awareness mode in app.config only. app.manifest is used to specify the supported Systems, as you're doing now. If you instead specify a DpiAwareness mode in app.manifest, this overrides whatever you have set in app.config (not recommended, the former is the intended behavior in .NET Fx 4.7.2+) -- If possible, move to .NET 7+, DpiAwareness is handled better (and it's actually being improved over time)

Comment: Thank you, just looked at .Net 7 and this is the way I shall be going as it does seem to address the scaling much better.